# SQL syntax: derive a column value to UPDATE that accounts for the value of a previous column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I need to UPDATE all the records with a value that is derived from the value of a previous record.

For example, given three fields `id`, `lft` and `rgt`, I need `lft` to be the value of the (((current `id` - 1)'s `lft`) + 2) and `rgt` to be the value of (((current `id` - 1)'s `rgt`) + 2).  I imply possession meaning `select lft where id=[current id-1]` and `select rgt where id=[current id-1]`

How do I express this in proper SQL syntax?

- Given the `id` of the record is `2`, the `lft`would be equal to `3`,
  the `rgt` would be equal to `4`.
- Given the `id` of the record is `3`,
  the `lft`would be equal to `5`, the `rgt` would be equal to `6`.
- Given the `id` of the record is `4`, the `lft`would be equal to `7`,
  the `rgt` would be equal to `8`.

So simple arithmetic operations (taking into account the value of `id`, for instance) will not easily account for the values of `lft` and `rgt`.

Thanks,

Matt

[update]

This is `MySQL 5.1.52`.

Comment: can't `UPDATE t SET lft = 2 * id - 1, rgt = 2 * id` suffice?

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: What about for the record with the lowest id?

Comment: Benoit, it looks like that does it, even accounting for the lowest `id` (`1`).  Simple math! :D  If you write that as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what you want the values to be for the record with the lowest id.

If you want the values to be unchanged for the lowest id (or when there is no `id - 1` record), you can `UPDATE`, using subqueries, `ORDER BY`, and `COALESCE`:

```
UPDATE t SET lft = COALESCE((SELECT lft FROM t t2 WHERE t2.id = t.id - 1) + 2, lft),
  rgt = COALESCE((SELECT rgt FROM t t2 WHERE t2.id = t.id - 1) + 2, rgt)
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```